# Visual Studio 2013 - disable highlight of same word in Javascript

Tags: visual-studio, highlight

One of the default features of the new Visual Studio 2013 is automatically highlighting all the occurances of the currently focused word (see screenshot below).

While some developers may consider this as something beneficial and productive, I don't like it personally and it even diverts my attention and interrupts.

I saw an answer on SO about how to disable this feature for C# (under Tools -> Text Editor), but couldn't find this settings for JavaScript...

Would be very grateful if someone can tell me how to disable this feature also for JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you need a plugin/extension. If you take a look at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS assembly, it does not contain properties to disable JS highlighting in VS

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Andrey, but do you know such a plug-in? And with this plug-in I will be able to disable this feature, not only manage it, right?

Comment: All the plug-ins I've found so far are related to enabling word highlighting and none of them lets me disable this feature. Alternatively, I thought of changing the background color definition of the highlighted words in the code (to white instead of grey), but couldn't find the specific definition for that in the list of colors under Fonts and Colors...

Answer (score 1):

Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Fonts and Colors --> Match color

[image: Screen shot of Visual Studio 2015 dialog for changing options.]

Then select foreground and background colors matching regular text.

Comment: Also, the highlighted reference color.

Answer (score 0):

After going through a lot of options, plug-ins and articles, I have found that the answer was not only so simple, but also was right under my nose...

Just going through the fonts & colors definitions of the text editor in VS, I came across the right definition for this behavior (something with "reference", if I remember correctly).

Now, if you don't mind, I will take my walk of shame. :)

Comment: To be precise, the definition under Fonts and Colors settings is called: Match Colors. Setting this definition to have a white background (not "default"!) fixed the issue in question here. FYI