# Can I turn off occurrence highlighting for the insertion point, editing js in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I write javascript in visual studio, the letters I am just typing are highlighted like this:
[image: starting to write]

and if there is another occurrence in the code...

[image: now we can see that the highlighting is about occurrences]

...that will also be highlighted.

So, this is obviously occurrence highlighting, counting the word being typed as an occurence and the word on the previous line as another.

How can I turn occurrence highlighting for insertion point off? It is annoying to always have to type code with occurrence highlighting background, which will be the case if the insertion point count as an occurrence. Also, I do not have a lot of use of knowing that the text I am typing is an occurence of the text I am typing.

In the second screenshot, I would like to only have the `console` before `.log("left");` highlighted because that is somewhere else in the document than the insertion point.

Comment: Did you try to take a look to that? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405611/visual-studio-2013-disable-highlight-of-same-word-in-javascript

Comment: @quirimmo I think that the question you linked to addresses how to get rid of occurrence matching instead of my problem, which is that the insertion point is counted as yet another occurrence.